# Using setTimeout for a counter creates a strange output?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I checked, doubled checked and rechecked this code to make sure it works properly (and it's simple) yet I cannot figure out why I get *~count: 17k* for the output, please help...

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>  
</head> 
<body onload = "counter()">
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
function counter()
{
   document.getElementById("div_1").innerHTML = "count: "+count;
   count++;
   setTimeout(counter(), 1000);
}
</script>
<div id = "div_1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` accepts a reference to a function

Comment: Yeah its a duplicate, didn't find that one. I dunno, I can't delete it now, I'll just accept Olegas answer. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not call, just reference

```
setTimeout(counter, 1000);
```

Comment: You mean I don't need a `()` at the end of `counter`? So in Javascript this is a reference just like a pointer in C/C++?

Comment: Yes. Then you write `counter()` you are calling your function. And, as it is returns nothing, it results in something like `setTimeout(undefined, 1000)` which results in nothing. When you write `setTimeout(counter, 1000)` you a reqeusting to call a function `counter` with 1000 ms delay.

Answer (score 1):

you are passing the result of `counter()` into `setTimout`, instead of just `setTimeout(counter, 1000)`. effectively, its just a recursive function. what you are doing is this:

```
var count = 0;
var counter = function(){
    count++;
    //Don't flood the console
    //console.log(count); 
    document.querySelector("#div1").innerHTML = "count: " + count;
    //you probably don't want this
    counter();
    //but this
    //setTimeout(counter, 1000);
};
```

your result of 17k is where `count` was at when javascript exhausted its call stack

Answer (score 0):

Wrap function in an anonymous function

```
setTimeout(function(){counter()}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tgLqH/

Comment: That looks interesting, although it makes the code more obfuscated than need be.